# posibilty to get service whithout moduleRef.get

Tags: nestjs

I Can take instance of service using this example:

```
export class GetEntityDomainService {
  constructor(private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef) { }

  getEntity(): void {
    const myObject = this.moduleRef.get(MyClassName);
  }
}
```

but how could I invoke a service instance outside of a class object
where I don't have a handle to moduleRef:
here is example from angular:

```
const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(providers);
const widgets: WidgetService = injector.get(WidgetService);
```

https://kevinphelps.me/blog/2017-01-17-using-angular-dependency-injection-in-node

whether is it possible to download an instance of the service without needing a moduleRef?

Thanks
Piotr

Comment: What would be the benefit of not using `moduleRef`?

Comment: I write some explanation, below

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons

sometimes I need to inject a service in a function, then I have to pass moduleRef to this function to make it possible

The second example is Command and Events -
for example  I create such an action, then I pass parameters to send to  handler,:

```
this.dispach(new Command (parameters ...))
```

Currently my actions know from which module they are triggered and in which module their handler is - so I won't send actions between wrong areas of the system (layers, dependencies). I check all this when executing

```
this.dispach (new Command ())
```

now I have to write such a dispatch as follows:

```
this.dispach (new Command (this.moduleRef, ... other parameters))
```

could  I create a moduleRef from the code?, it would facilitate the process of creating an action and eliminate the need to pass moduleRef

but I don't know if it will help me
as I analyzed DI nest, it works differently from angular
The service knows where it was declared and when it injects something in it, it uses the tokens declared in this module
I suppose I will only be able to inject general scope